# How to get exe stdout in real time in GUI though cmd is executing in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt

```
with Popen([cmd command], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, 
    universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        log.insertPlainText(line)
```

I want to run exe file through Python code and get the print content from pyqt in real time. So I wrote the code as above. However, after all the results printed in cmd are executed, the exe contents are printed all at once. I would like to receive it in real-time in GUI even though cmd is still working, rather than making it output to pyqt after all the contents of cmd are executed. I want an argument value or other way to solve this.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear to me if you want to process the exe's output line by line or something else. What I (seemingly) understand is that you get all output at once. Is this correct?

Comment: @Wolf I have implemented pyqt GUI separately, and I have created a separate python file for all actions. Do you know how to make it work as a Python file, not on the GUI?

Comment: Maybe replace `log.insertPlainText(line)` by `print(line)` and the `import subprocess` before the block shown. You are probably able to check the behavior interactively.

Comment: @Wolf I already checked that print(line) results output properly, but I want exe's output to be seen as log on the GUI, not as cmd's output. So that's why I used log.insertPlainText.

Comment: What do you mean by `properly`? If the simpler version works with line-by-line output, could it be that the `log` isn't updated while the output is processed in the `for` loop?

Comment: When **print(line)**, the results are output in real time from cmd(So I used the word 'properly'), but the problem is that **log.insertPlaintext(line)** results are not output in real time on the GUI.

Comment: That's what I expected: events (=signals) are not handled meanwhile. Some frameworks offer functions to force event handling, I'm not sure pyqt has something like that. But the Qt way shown in the answer is of course preferable.

Comment: @Wolf Thank you! It's a little sad news for me, but you've been helpful. I'm constantly looking for a Popen argument that can force that method. If I find out, I'll write it down here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QtCore.QProcess` has `readyReadStandardError` and `readyReadStandardOutput` signals which emited once data on stdout and stderr ready

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

def buffer_to_str(buf):
    codec = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8")
    return str(codec.toUnicode(buf))

class Process(QtCore.QObject):

    stdout = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    stderr = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def start(self, program, args):
        process = QtCore.QProcess()
        process.setProgram(program)
        process.setArguments(args)
        process.readyReadStandardError.connect(lambda: self.stderr.emit(buffer_to_str(process.readAllStandardError())))
        process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(lambda: self.stderr.emit(buffer_to_str(process.readAllStandardOutput())))
        process.finished.connect(self.finished)
        process.start()
        
        self._process = process

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    process = Process()
    
    log = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
    log.show()
    
    process.stderr.connect(log.appendPlainText)

    cmd = "ping"
    args = ["google.com"]
    process.start(cmd, args)

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: interesting approach which may be the best solution for OP. Do you maybe know why the problem occurs that OP describes?

Comment: @Wolf I believe that python subprocess can only be read syncronously in blocking manner, which doesn't allow it to be used in main gui thread, you have to move it to `QThread` or just use `QtCore.QProcess`. OP can try `asyncio` python module, I dont know how to mix it with gui though.

Comment: Ah, seems like this. I wasn't sure if `Popen` creates a separate thread for this.